# how to sum money value in firebase realtime android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to sum money value in firebase realtime android studio

Hello how can I sum a value with the existing node value?

Every time onDataChange is called, sum the value with the value of the "money" node of the firebase
any help is welcome.

my code

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            ref.child("Users").child(userUid).child("money").setValue("350");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making simple write operation, you can use [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Just refer below code.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users").child(userUid).child("money");


ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Object currentMoney = mutableData.getValue();
        int totalMoney = 0;
        if (currentMoney == null) {
             totalMoney = moneyToAdd;
        } else {
             totalMoney = Integer.parseInt(currentMoney) + moneyToAdd;
        }

        mutableData.setValue(totalMoney);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object', 'int' on currentMoney + moneyToAdd

Comment: i'm define this  int moneyToAdd = 100;

Comment: Hello, I managed to implement without errors but something that was working now is giving an error on this line long v = Long.parseLong ((String) dataSnapshot.getValue ()); this line of code is from the previous activity when opening cassinopayment generates this error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null" would you know how to fix it? could help me I believe that the solution you gave really works but this error appeared now and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: how can I pass a null value for this line long v = Long.parseLong ((String) dataSnapshot.getValue ());

sorry I'm new

Comment: Replace below line `long v = Long.parseLong ((String) dataSnapshot.getValue ());` with `long v = 0; if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){ v = Long.parseLong ((String) dataSnapshot.getValue ());}`

Comment: I set private int moneyToAdd = 9; but node money has not been updated am i doing something wrong?

Comment: debug marker ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() results 
                      DataSnapshot { key = VsJZ6QEEzgMmD1nUxcYylaZZX0r1, value = {fullname=test test2, address=instagram, helpsms=sms, phone=55555555555, email=test@a.com, money=350, cassinotime=5, cassinoprofit=250, cassino={cassinotime=10000, cassinoprofit=250}} }

Comment: hoo thanks man one problem I had 10 in node money as I set int moneyToAdd = 100; when updated it generated a value of 910 in the node "money" how to fix this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. Recheck your logic implementation once.